# ROS2 systemd service launch to ROS topic

Tags: ros2, ros2-launch

We are trying to launch a ROS2 subscriber node and publisher node on boot. We are using a systemd service file to launch our launch.py file. When running `systemctl status`
and viewing the systemctl log, we can see our nodes running and communicating. However, when we run `ros2 topic list`, we cannot see the topic over which the nodes are communicating. Why is this and how do we “re-route” the information from the systemctl logs to ROS2 such that we can view the topic and messages directly in ROS2?

(We confirmed that the nodes themselves work when running `ros2 run <node_name>`. Here is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=ROS 2 Node Launch Service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="HOME=root"
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/worm7_ros2_launch.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/worm7/worms_ws/install/setup.bash

ros2 launch startup startup.launch.py
```

Here is the launch file:

```
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='startup',
            namespace='startup',
            executable='listener',
            name='listener'
        ),
        Node(
            package='startup',
            namespace = 'startup',
            executable='talker',
            name='talker'
        )
        
    ])
```

The code for the publisher and subscriber nodes can be found here: https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When running at a system process it will have a different user and environment. I would suggest making sure that you don't have any settings is places like your `.bashrc` file that is setting up your environment differently. Or elsewhere in your user directory or system in general.